# ubuntu with win7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have ubuntu 13.04 installed on my computer.  Ubuntu on 130gb partition. Ubuntu swap on 10gb separate partition. In addition 300gb partition for data. now i want to:

1. resize the data partition from 300gb to 250gb.
2. live the ubunt os but resize the ubuntu partition from 130gb to 50gb.
3. install win7 64 bit on a new partition 130gb (50gb from data + 80gb from ubuntu).
4. enable dual boot - ubuntu and win7.

Thank you for help,
David.

Comment: was is the order of the partitions ?

Answer (score 0):

First you need an **Ubuntu Live CD** or **USB drive** and make a **live boot**.
Then start **GParted** app.

You can easily make changes in the partition for Ubuntu and other data using this app (Answer for Qn.1 & Qn.2).  For any clarifications , try the following link:
http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/.

You may easily install windows on the partition you prefer (Qn.3).

After installation,  if you don't get the GRUB (Boot menu) try the following link :
[How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows) (Qn.4).